# Which JS strategy is better for merging multiple data sources into one?

Tags: javascript, json, oop, refactoring, babeljs

I'm currently refactoring old code; my boss wants all of our platforms' JS rewritten in ES6 -- I'm a novice with ES6; understand the basic `const func = () => {...};` but still have yet to fully grasp everything it has to offer.

**We do not use `React` anywhere in our platform (not yet, at least).**

One of our modules depends on **3 external data sources**, all of which are JSON RESTful APIs. The external data sources must be unified, formatted and saved using a single object-literal template. **For the purpose of clarity**, the object-literal template is as follows:

```json
{
  'id_str': '',
  'content_author': '',
  'content_body': '',
  'content_image_url': '',
  'content_source': '',
  'content_title': '',
  'content_type': '',
  'date_published': '',
  'date_published_timestamp': '',
  'embed_url': '',
  'mb_strlen': ''
}
```

Up until recently, this data was retrieved, parsed and formatted using **9 separate function declarations**, all of which were housed in a single file.

My initial thought would be to export the public functions using `module.exports` like...

```js
const _formatDate = function( args ){...},
      _formatTime = function( args ){...},
      _formatUrl  = function( args ){...};

module.exports = {
  'contentContainer': function( args ){...},
  'contentFilters': function( args ){...},
  'contentInfinite': function( args ){...}
  'dataGetResponse': function( args ){...},
  'dataParseResponse': function( args ){...},
  'renderJST': function( args ){...}
};
```

...but I also have a strong feeling that this is not considered ***best practice*** for ES6, particularly when ES6 classes are supposed to "ease the burden" of prototypal inheritance.

With that, is it better to write this as a **ES6 class**, **object-literal** or keep it as 9 separate **function declarations**?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and I'm open to any ideas. My main concern is what will be best for ***performance*** and ***long-term maintenance*** or *future-proofing*.

Cheers!

Comment: This area of questioning is more appropriate for [codereview.se]. But you can't generally post pseudo-code there, you need to post a full working example that they can critique.

Comment: @Barmar I'll definitely remember that. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Best not to use `code blocks` for emphasis. If you wish to keep the private functions actually private, define them in the module, while only exporting the public functions

Comment: @Snow I just updated my example using your recommendations. Thank you.